# Are there any examples of bash being embedded in a program?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Are there any examples of a Unix shell like bash, zsh being embedded in an program, similar to how PostgreSQL has extensions like pl/Python and pl/Lua embedded into them?

Comment: `bash` is not designed as a general purpose language suitable for data processing (like Python and Lua are): it's designed to facilitate running other programs and handling files.

Comment: I am not interested in bash as a way of processing data or manipulating the programs own structures, but more as a program having bash directly built-in and having direct access to the shell's own structures.

Answer (score 2):

Of course a modern shell like Bash has many "internal" commands, but at its core, it is designed to launch external programs and access file-system objects.

It is not suitable as a language to control internal features of a host program. As of myself, I've never seen any example of that. And if it was, I would have been rather skeptical about that choice.

Languages designated for that exact purpose like Lua or JavaScript are definitively a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

If there are, they're very rare. I've not seen anything like that in my long career. Having done some work on the `bash` shell, I'm not sure it's the sort of thing I'd enjoy embedding :-)

Instead, what you tend to see are shell scripts which are the controlling portion, using tools like SQL command-line programs to do the lower-level work, like:

```
for tblvw in systables sysviews ; do
    db2 "select name from sysibm.${tblvw}"
done
```

Or you sometimes see programs running an *external* shell process to perform some action, with a `system()`-like call.